# Max string length for Resources.resw UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, translation

I am trying to see if I can set a specific max character count to my Resources.resw so that when it is translated in another language (greek) I could for example say that this key value cannot be more than 9 characters.

So the if I had the value "follow" in english, its greek value is "aκολουθηστε". However I would like for the translation to not exceed 9 characters.  Is there a way for me to specific the max characters count for a translation in the resw file?

Update :

I have the issue with "Follow" for example that is in a very tight space that is not expandable, if the translated version is more then 9 characters then it overflows "breaks" the UI.

Comment: What is the purpose for this? Surely you would want the direct translation as it is. How are you expecting to handle it if it would be longer than a set number of max characters?

Comment: Do you want a build error?

Comment: Obviously, there is no such function in VS. But I think you may try to write a VS extension to do this as Resources.resw is a XML file.